# Is it possible for vba excel property to return word.range?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want my class property to return `word.range` object which then is to be inserted into a word document. The reason I want it to return the `word.range`, not a `string` is because I want the text to be pre-formatted (namely, some parts of the text to be bold). Here's the code I tried:

```
Property Get wordRange() As word.Range

    Dim result As word.Range
    'invalid use of new keyword
    Set result = New word.Range
    result.text = "the text here is bold"
    result.Bold = True
    wordRange = result
End Property
```

Is it possible to create a `word.range` object in the "vacuum" and return it? If so, can it contain both bold and regular formatting?

Comment: You can't `New` up an `Excel.Range` either ;-) You need a `Word.Application` instance with a `Word.Document` to get a `Word.Range`, similar to how you need an `Excel.Worksheet` instance to pull an `Excel.Range` from.

Answer (score 1):

First of all @Mathieu Guindon is right.
I am experiencing with word, so I tried to find a solution for the problem. If your class creates a separate instance of  Word.Application and Word.Document, than it can be used as it required.
I added the class initialization and termination, so the class (named as clsWrd) is:

```
Private wApp As Word.Application
Private wDoc As Word.Document

Property Get wordRange() As Word.Range
    Dim result As Word.Range
    Set result = wDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
    result.Text = "the text here is bold"
    result.Bold = True
    Set wordRange = result
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set wApp = New Word.Application
    'App.Visible = True
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    wApp.Quit False
    Set wApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

This part demostrate the use of it

```
Sub test()
    'Create and initialize the class
    Dim nk As clsWrd
    Set nk = New clsWrd
    
    'Simulate/demostrate the main word application
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Set wApp = New Word.Application
    wApp.Visible = True
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add
    Dim wrngTarget As Word.Range
    Set wrngTarget = wDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
    
    'Use the object
    Dim wrngSource As Word.Range
    Set wrngSource = nk.wordRange
    'wrngSource.Copy
    'wrngTarget.Paste
    wrngTarget.FormattedText = wrngSource.FormattedText
End Sub
```

Comment: Whilst this solution would work it is overly complex. The simplest solution is to just add the required text to the target document and format it as required. BTW, there is no need to use the clipboard in your solution. The last two lines could be replaced with `wrngTarget.FormattedText = wrngSource.FormattedText`

Comment: Thank you Timothy. I agree with you, that it is  unnecessarily complex. I updated the solution regarding the FormattedText property.